# Detect which dropdown box was clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am executing the same function on multiple dropdown boxes with `id: assignee, status , priority`.

```
$("#assignee , #status , #priority").change(function() { 

//text here

}
```

But I want to know which specific dropdown was clicked. Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the following:

```
$("#assignee, #status, #priority").change(function() { 
    if (this.id === "assignee") { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this. In any event handler this points to an element where actual event happened:

```
$("#assignee , #status , #priority").change(function() { 
    var changedElementID = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

Another option is to use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$("#assignee , #status , #priority").change(function(e) { 
        var changedElementID = $(e.target).attr("id");
    }
```

And [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) you can find more detailed information about other event object properties.

Note that both `this` and `e.target` are DOM objects, not jQuery objects. So you need to wrap it with jquery like in my code above to use jQuery functions. If simply get an id - you can use directly `this.id` or `e.target.id` which is faster.

Comment: You really should access the `id` property directly, rather than using the `.attr()` function (even when unnecessarily using jQuery it should be `.prop()`), so: `this.id` or `e.target.id`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Agree. Just wanted to highlight that that both point to regular DOM objects and should be wrapped with jQuery to get its functionality. Updated my answer to make it more clear

Comment: FWIW there is no need in `e.target` here, `this` is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

When the event is triggered, inside the event handler function `this` refers to the element that triggered the event, so:

```
$('#assignee, #status, #priority').change(function(e) {
    // Use 'this' to refer to the element that triggered the event
    console.log(this.id);
    // will output assignee, status or priority depending on which changed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use target :

```
$("#assignee , #status , #priority").change(function(e) { 
        var changedElementID = $(e.target).attr("id");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are binding your `<option>` at that point pass `this` to the function and use your own code

```
$("#assignee , #status , #priority").change(function(boxID) { 
console.log($(boxID).val());    //Gives you the value of the selected drop down


//text here

}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The first argument passed to the event handler function is the event itself, regardless of what you call it. So `boxID` inside that anonymous function is the event, not the element that triggered the `change` event.

Comment: Also sounds suspiciously like you're advocating the use of inline event handler attributes (`onchange="foo()"`, etc) which is a horrendously bad and outdated practice.