# Determine Which Dropdown Was Clicked Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several dropdowns on my page and I am trying to get the id of the dropdown I selected using jquery. I have searched stackoverflow and found a post at this link [Detect which dropdown box was clicked in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725785/detect-which-dropdown-box-was-clicked-in-jquery).

The problem is although my code is exactly the same aside from the names of the ids, it does not work. Please see my code below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FirstId", "#SecondId", "#ThirdId").change(function () {
            if (this.id === "FirstId") {
                alert($("#FirstId").val());
            }
            else if (this.id === "SecondId") {
                alert($("#SecondId").val());
            }
            else 
                alert($("#ThirdId").val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.

```
$("select").change(function () {
                alert("ID : " + $(this).attr("id")); 
                alert("Value : " + $(this).val());                
        });
```

Example :http://jsfiddle.net/ta4eLLe2/

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for selecting multiple IDs is wrong. It should be:

```
$("#FirstId, #SecondId, #ThirdId")
```

One string with all the selectors separated by commas, not three different arguments.

Go back and look at the question you linked to.